# How do I write this symbol (showed in picture, upright angle in math mode, not 180 rotated "A")

Tags: math-mode, angle

How do I write this symbol (showed in picture, upright angle in math mode, not 180 rotated "A")

[image]

Comment: `\forall`......

Comment: Yes, thanks. This answered my question. Have a nice day!

Comment: To find a command relating to a special character, You can use "Detexify" (https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html)